# Active Directory B2B External Idp integration

Tags: azure-active-directory

Azure AD B2B has a preconfigured Google integration and the ability add external Idp. Has any one configured it with Okta?.

Looking for guidance - What do we need from Okta to get the meta data etc.

Tried the Google B2b integration and it works. But stuck trying to create external SAML provider for integration with Okta. Are there any step by step guidance or instructions to get the info from Okta to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the generic documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/direct-federation) on the **preview** feature. That is a starting point for your endeavor.

Using this documentation (and respective OKTA one - probably [this one](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/saml-application-setup/overview/)) you should be able to configure OKTA as a SAML IdP for Azure AD Direct Federation feature.

Important terms in that setup: OKTA will be the `SAMP IdP (Identity Provider)` while Azure AD will be `SAML SP (Service Provider)`.

There is nothing more concrete about integrating OKTA as IdP for direct federation. Also please note that this feature is in preview in AAD.